# Drag and Drop Rearrangable ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am using the following link to make a rearrangable listview
https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview
Please let me know how can I remove the handler in the right and make the listview rearrangable just by clicking and dragging in the list item itself...
I had been trying several strategies and couldn't find a solution...
Thank you for your valuable time in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Since long-press to start dragging is a pretty common technique, I would say set the following xml attrs:

```
dslv:drag_start_mode="onLongPress"
dslv:drag_handle_id="@id/my_list_item"
```

where "my_list_item" is the `android:id` of the (top-level) View of your list item layout.

Comment: Need to use (dslv:drag_handle_id="@+id/list_of_items")